# How do you make this multiplication table in c++?

Tags: c++

C++, Using iostream and conio.
Can someone show me a sample program for a multiplication table that would result this example.
Input is 5
Output is the multiplication table for 1 to 5
Example:

```
1*1=1
1*2=2
```

All the way to

```
5*10=50
```

Comment: You could use a `for` loop. Could you please show your code so far and clarify specifically where you are stuck?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework question does not show any effort

Comment: how do **you** make this multiplication table? Show us your code and let us know where you got stuck, then we can help you

Comment: int num,a,b;    cin>>num;    for(a=1;a<=10;a++)     {     for(b=1;b<=10;b++) cout<<b<<"*"<<num<<"="<<b*num<<endl;

Comment: @RyuzakiKirigaya:  Please don't post code in comments, it is not very readable.  Please edit your post with any code (as text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            cout<<i * j<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it has to be vertical. Example: 1*1=1 to 1*10=10, 2*1=2 to 2*10= 20 then 3*1=3 up to 3*10=30

Comment: @RyuzakiKirigaya Updated. This was because you're a new contributor, But try **Not** to ask for codes. You can share your own code and if it doesn't work, Ask for help about it.

Comment: okay thanks alot though